# SELECT statement taking more than 1 minute to execute

Tags: python, mysql, query-optimization

I am working on a program in python to parse my database. It current has nearly 6 million records in the table.

Because of this when I perform a query then it takes too much time to execute.

Here is a two examples:

```
Attempting to execute: SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE email = 'xxx@xx.com'
{'password': u'****', 'ip_address': u'***.***.***.***', 'email': u'xxx@xx.com'}
Time taken: 63.6909999847 seconds
_________________________________________________________________________________

Attempting to execute: SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE email REGEXP '/rosic/g' LIMIT 200
Time taken: 212.973999977 seconds
_________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: You should construct an *index* in the database.

Comment: Could you explain how I would do that?

Comment: The rex however cannot be automated, afaik.

Comment: 1. Add appropriate indexes to your schema. 2. Try and use LIKE instead of REGEXP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should concentrate on the `WHERE` part and specifically you should have an index created on `email` column since you are having a filter condition on it `WHERE email = 'xxx@xx.com'`

```
CREATE INDEX idx_email ON accounts (email(30));
```

You can use an `ALTER` statement to do so

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ADD INDEX idx_email (email(30));
```

Per your comment since it's a `TEXT` type column you need to specify the index length. See MySQL documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html. Also, you may consider looking into `FULLTEXT` search indexing feature

Comment: How would I do so?

Comment: I got an error from MySQL midway through it: `Error in query (1170): BLOB/TEXT column 'email' used in key specification without a key length`

Comment: @J.Doe, check edit again and post all this info beforehand

Comment: A regular index will _not_ be used for the query in question.  Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to prove it.  `FULLTEXT` may work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a MySQL developer but try this:-

`CREATE INDEX acct_ix ON accounts (email);`

Answer (score 0):

Also you should return only the column that you need. Select * is not a good practice.

I also agree with the previous post, you should create index on the email field.

Finally the LIKE function has better performance than the REGEX function.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, `LIKE` will be faster, but possibly not twice as fast.